# using setw with user-defined ostream operators

Tags: c++, boost, stream

How do I make setw or something similar (boost format?) work with my user-defined ostream operators?  setw only applies to the next element pushed to the stream.

For example:

```
cout << "    approx: " << setw(10) << myX;
```

where myX is of type X, and I have my own

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const X &g) {
    return os << "(" << g.a() << ", " << g.b() << ")";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make sure that all your output is sent to the stream as part of the same call to `operator<<`. A straightforward way to achieve this is to use an auxiliary `ostringstream` object:

```
#include <sstream>

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const X & g) {

    ostringstream oss;
    oss << "(" << g.a() << ", " << g.b() << ")";
    return os << oss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe like so using the [width](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/width/) function:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const X &g) {
    int w = os.width();
    return os << "(" << setw(w) << g.a() << ", " << setw(w) << g.b() << ")";
}
```

Comment: This way the total width is 3 times w and there is too much white space between the individual items.

Comment: With os.width() you should be capable of fixing it yourself.