# what is wrong with c++ streams when using boost.python?

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

**Update 2:  I'm not sure why this is still being upvoted (March 2014).  This appears to be fixed since I asked this question many years ago.  Make sure you're using a recent version of boost.**

**UPDATE: Perhaps C++ streams need to be initialized in order to format numbers, and the initialization is not happening when the shared library is loaded in Python?**

I am calling

```
cout << 1 << "!" << endl;
```

in a method that is exported to a shared library via boost.python.  It doesn't print anything, but if I do

```
cout << "%" << "!" << endl;
```

it works.

This is important because I want to do this:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream &os, const Bernoulli& b) {
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << b.p() * 100.0 << "%";
    return os << oss.str();
}
```

I exposed that by doing this:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libdistributions)
{
    class_<Bernoulli>("Bernoulli")
        .def(init<>())
        .def(init<double>())

        .def("p", &Bernoulli::p)
        .def("set_p", &Bernoulli::set_p)
        .def("not_p", &Bernoulli::not_p)

        .def("Entropy", &Bernoulli::Entropy)
        .def("KL", &Bernoulli::KL)
        .def(self_ns::str(self))
    ;
}
```

but when I call the `str` method in python on a Bernoulli object, I get nothing.  I suspect the simpler cout problem is related.

Comment: I did not have problem with iostreams and boost.python... maybe the problem comes from a more subtile bug? However, the technique in the docs (http://1dl.us/dAD) didn't work for me, I had to write `.def("__str__", &print_wrapper<Bernouilli>)`. What is `self_ns`?. Also, in your method, why not just `{return os << b.p() * 100.0 << "%"; }`?

Comment: @rafak the reason for doing it via ostringstream is explained in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249018/using-setw-with-user-defined-ostream-operators

Comment: @rafak where is `print_wrapper` defined?  I can't find it in boost.

Comment: I should have said that it is mine: template <class C>
inline std::string print_wrapper(const C& obj)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << obj;
    return os.str(); }

Comment: @Neil G: nice trick for doing it via ostringstream!

Comment: @rafak FYI: print_wrapper has the same as the usual str solution for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828903/build-problems-when-adding-str-method-to-boost-python-c-class/3084341#3084341

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also run into this problem a while ago, using self_ns as outlined in the answers here [Build problems when adding `__str__` method to Boost Python C++ class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828903/build-problems-when-adding-str-method-to-boost-python-c-class/3084341#3084341)

The reason for using self_ns is explained by Dave himself here http://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2004-February/006496.html

---

Just for the sake of debugging, please try

```
inline std::string toString(const Bernoulli& b) 
{
   std::ostringstream s;
   s << b;
   return s.str(); 
}
```

And replace `.def(self_ns::str(self))` with

```
class_<Bernoulli>("Bernoulli")
[...]
.def("__str__", &toString)
```

Comment: I used self_ns as shown in the question, and it didn't fix this problem.

Comment: Can you try `.def(self_ns::str(self_ns::self))`?

Comment: Also you could try to add a `std::cout << "hello world << std::endl" inside your operator<< and report if your function gets called at all.

Comment: Hi, I did try that code.  I'm pretty sure that Boost.Python is not properly initializing the integer-to-string code for streams.  Using a printf works, but using ostream doesn't.

Comment: @Neil G: Did you try what I wrote under "Just for the sake of debugging", did that work?

Comment: Thanks for your help Brandsmeier.  I retried the self_ns::str method and it worked.  I guess it must have been fixed since I posted this question two years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `boost::format` instead? Since you are already using `boost`, it shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

```
boost::format( "%d%%" ) % ( b.p() * 100.0 )
```

Another thing, try passing `std::endl` explicitly to the output `os`.

Comment: Thanks.  The number is still not being shown, but the "%" sign is there. It appears that the buffer in which the number is stringified is not being created.

Comment: Hm. I'll try to reproduce the problem then.

Comment: Thank you.  Please let me know if you can't reproduce it and if you ever find a solution.

Comment: Ok, I wrote an empty `Bernoulli` class, with `p` defined as `double p() {return 2.5;}`; in Python, `str(b)` prints `250%` as expected. I used boost 1.42 and Python 2.5. Which versions are you using?

Comment: I'm using boost 1.48 and Python 3.1 now.

Comment: I am going to do some more testing with your solution and then maybe start a bounty.  It's not a big deal for me anymore, but it seems that many other people are running into this given the upvotes on the question.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried flushing the stream prior to using the .str() method?

```
oss << b.p() * 100.0 << "%" << std::flush;
```